# Hadoop Create your own program

Tags: netbeans, hadoop

I am new toy Hadoop and i am wondering how to write a program in Netbeans.

The whole idea is to take the source code of word count and then write a new program. The steps i followed are those:

1. In Netbeans i created a new Class . (SplitData).
2. Copy- Pasted the entire code of word count and then renamed the class name.

But i have problems in Netbeans. It cannot find the imports.

Comment: You have to put the Hadoop jar into the classpath, I'm sure people more familiar with netbeans will help you on that.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I assumed that you created already the project and then add your SplitData class. In the project tab(in default on your left) you have your created project. Expand it and right-click on the "Librabies" -> "Add JAR/Folder..." and then find the hadoop jar file(in linux a default location /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop.jar). That's it.